# ROS + Google Colab

Tags: linux, robots.txt

Olá. Gostaria de fazer o ROS (Robot Operating System) funcionar no Google Colab. Alguém tem algum exemplo de como fazer isso? Tava dando uma olhada nesses 2 links:

https://github.com/RoboStack/jupyter-ros/issues/11

No link, parece que o autor faz funcionar, no link:

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1QpSNBB339OoCJaVJ4_3bfikt0ygOC2NV

Com base no link acima, fiz o seguinte código para instalação do ROS:

```
#@title Install ROS melodic

ROS_CODE_NAME = 'melodic'

#from http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu

#1.2 Setup sources.list
!echo "1.2 Doing"
!sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'
!echo "1.2 Done"

# 1.3 Setup keys
!echo "1.3 Doing"
#!sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-key 421C365BD9FF1F717815A3895523BAEEB01FA116
!sudo apt-key del 421C365BD9FF1F717815A3895523BAEEB01FA116
!sudo apt-key del B01FA116

!apt --fix-broken install

!sudo dpkg --configure -a
!sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -f install

# add the new key
!sudo -E apt-key adv --keyserver 'hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80' --recv-key C1CF6E31E6BADE8868B172B4F42ED6FBAB17C654

!sudo apt clean && sudo apt update

!sudo apt install
!echo "1.3 Done"

# 1.4 Installation
!echo "1.4 Doing"
#!sudo apt update  &> /dev/null
!sudo apt update
#!sudo apt upgrade  &> /dev/null
!sudo apt upgrade
!echo "1.4 Done"

# Desktop-Full Install:
!echo "1.4.1 Doing"
#!sudo apt install ros-$ROS_CODE_NAME-desktop-full  &> /dev/null
!sudo apt install ros-melodic-desktop-full
!echo "1.4.2 Done"

# 1.5 Initialize rosdep
!echo "1.5 Doing"
#!sudo rosdep init  &> /dev/null
!sudo rosdep init
#!rosdep update  &> /dev/null
!rosdep update
!echo "1.5 Done"


# 1.7 Getting rosinstall (python)
!echo "1.7 Doing"
#!sudo apt install python-rosinstall  &> /dev/null
!sudo apt install python-rosinstall
#!sudo apt install python-catkin-tools  &> /dev/null
!sudo apt install python-catkin-tools
!echo "1.7 Done"
!echo "All Done"
```

Vários módulos do python apresentam o problema:

```
dpkg: error processing package python-rosdep-modules (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ros-melodic-rqt-robot-monitor:
 ros-melodic-rqt-robot-monitor depends on python-rospkg-modules; however:
  Package python-rospkg-modules is not installed.
```

Além disso, vários módulos apresentam o seguinte erro também (mesmo rodando o comando citado, não resolve o problema):

```
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-rosdep-modules : Depends: python-rospkg-modules (>= 1.2.7) but it is not installed
                         Depends: python-rosdistro-modules (>= 0.7.5) but it is not installed
 ros-melodic-rqt-gui : Depends: python-rospkg-modules but it is not installed
 ros-melodic-rqt-robot-monitor : Depends: python-rospkg-modules but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Por um acaso alguém já fez algo parecido?

Obrigado!